# SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 17

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, backend

In a product warranty registration, there is a syntax error in `JSON.parse()` but I can not find this error. this is the first application in AngularJS that I am doing, usually I program in Java. I have an API developed in PHP that does the Back-end, and a controller that makes the communication between the API and the view.

My controller:

```
function adicionarGarantiaCtrl(
    $scope,
    $rootScope,
    constants,
    connectServerFactory
    ngDialog
) {
    var METHOD_GET;
    var METHOD_POST;
    var URL_ADICIONAR_LINK_GARANTIA;

    init();
    function init() {
        METHOD_GET = constants.METHOD_GET();
        METHOD_POST = constants.METHOD_POST();
        URL_ADICIONAR_LINK_GARANTIA = constants.URL_ADICIONAR_LINK_GARANTIA();
    }

    $scope.salvarGarantia = function() {
        var salvar = {
            "ano": $scope.add_ano,
            "mes": $scope.add_mes,
            "link": $scope.add_link,
            "num_mes": $scope.add_nmes
        };

        console.log("TESTE adicionarGarantiaCtrl");
        console.log(salvar);

        connectServerFactory.conectar(
            METHOD_POST,
            URL_ADICIONAR_LINK_GARANTIA,
            salvar,
            function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $rootScope.garantia_ano = data.ano;
                $rootScope.garantia_mes = data.mes;
                $rootScope.garantia_link = data.link;
                $rootScope.garantia_num_mes = data.num_mes;
            },
            function(erro) {
                console.log(erro);
            }
        );

        ngDialog.close();
    }
}
```

My API..

```
function adicionar_garantia() {
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $garantia = json_decode($request->getBody());

    $sql = "INSERT INTO garantia(" .
        "garantia, troca_distribuidor, garantia_fabrica, garantia_antecipada" .
    ") VALUES (" .
        ":garantia, :troca_distribuidor, :garantia_fabrica, :garantia_antecipada" .
    ")";

    try {
        $db = getDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("garantia", $garantia->garantia);
        $stmt->bindParam("troca_distribuidor", $garantia->troca_distribuidor);
        $stmt->bindParam("garantia_fabrica", $garantia->garantia_fabrica);
        $stmt->bindParam("garantia_antecipada", $garantia->garantia_antecipada);
        $stmt->execute();
        $garantia->id_garantia = $db->lastInsertId();
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($garantia);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the Network response tab in your Developer console. You're not getting the response you're expecting from your PHP script.

Comment: you need to wrap the `$e->getMessage()` string in quotes, `'{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'` should be `'{"error":{"text":"'. $e->getMessage() .'"}}'`

Comment: Scagood it worked perfectly, it returned me an error that was in my sql and I already solved it. thank you so much.

Comment: Reply the post and I will put it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having here is the JSON in the `catch` block is not quoting the message.
The following line:

```
echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
```

Should become:

```
echo '{"error":{"text":"'. $e->getMessage() .'"}}';
```

Perhaps a better option would be to continue using the `json_encode` function as you did in the `try` section of the `try catch`. This is both (In my opinion) easier to debug, and easier to read.

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'error' => array(
        'text' => $e->getMessage()
    )
));
```